# How to change Mysql collation to Turkish?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql schema with utf8 charset and  utf8_unicode_ci collation. Problem is when I want to query some Turkish characters Mysql can't determine this character is Turkish or not.

In Turkish there is "İ" which is capital "i" and "I" which is capital "ı".

```
SELECT name FROM students where name = "testĞÇ"; //returns "testğç" which is true
SELECT name FROM students where name = "testI"; //Mysql thinks "I" character is capital "i" and returns null
```

my students table data;

```
testğç
testı
```

**EDIT:** My "name" column's collation is utf8_unicode_ci.

```
SELECT name FROM students where name = "testI" collate utf8_turkish_ci; //still returns null
```

**EDIT 2:** When I change "name" column's collation from utf8_unicode_ci to utf8_turkish_ci, It works well. But this time I need to change all my table column's collation's to  utf8_turkish_ci and I don't know it will cause any loss of data.

Answer (score 1):

Use the appropriate Turkish collation.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT "testı" = "testI" collate utf8_unicode_ci;
+--------------------------------------------+
| "testı" = "testI" collate utf8_unicode_ci  |
+--------------------------------------------+
|                                          0 |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT "testı" = "testI" collate utf8_turkish_ci;
+--------------------------------------------+
| "testı" = "testI" collate utf8_turkish_ci  |
+--------------------------------------------+
|                                          1 |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I also get same results when I query your scripts but thing is my column's collation is utf8_unicode_ci and when I query with adding "collate utf8_turkish_ci" at the end of the script, still getting null result.

Answer (score 0):

As the Ğ and Ç are working, and I / İ is not, it sounds like a mySQL bug.

A quick check of the mySQL forums has someone recommending using Latin5

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?147,251229,257016#msg-257016

Answer (score 0):

I know you didn't specify a language but I think this could help you. I had found a script somewhere when I had the same problem like you and fixed the problem with running this code:

```
<?php 
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'db_name';
$collation = "utf8_general_ci";
$charset = "utf8";

mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname);
mysql_query("ALTER DATABASE $dbname COLLATE $collation");
$result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES"); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) { 
    mysql_query("ALTER TABLE $row[0] COLLATE $collation"); 
    $result1 = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $row[0]"); 
    while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) { 
        if (preg_match('~char|text|enum|set~', $row1["Type"])) { 
            mysql_query("ALTER TABLE $row[0] MODIFY $row1[Field] $row1[Type] CHARACTER SET $charset"); 
            mysql_query("ALTER TABLE $row[0] MODIFY $row1[Field] $row1[Type] COLLATE $collation DEFAULT '$row1[Default]'"); 
            echo $row[0] . "->" . $row1[Field] . "->" . $row1[Type] . " is now UTF8\n";
        }
    }
}
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

It simply fetches all tables and changes it's collation to `utf8_general_ci` as it supports most chars available. Then your newly added datas would have the correct charset.

The main codes that do the trick are:

For the database:

```
ALTER DATABASE [db_name] COLLATE [collation]
```

For the individual tables:

```
ALTER TABLE [table_name] MODIFY [column_name] [column_type] CHARACTER SET [charset]
ALTER TABLE [table_name] MODIFY [column_name] [column_type] COLLATE [collation]
```